# Exported a project as library, cant find resources

Tags: c#, dll, icons

I exported a project which uses some files as icons, as a class library.  Now when I use the library in another project, it is unable to find those icons. How can I export it in such a way that they are available even in the project that uses the library?

Thanks and regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the icons to the library project and mark them as `Embedded Resource` files.  Then use the `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(...)` function to read them.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your resources using the resource designer, open the designer and change the "Access modifier" combo from "Internal" to "Public".